# C# Call method from another class

Tags: c#, class, methods, public

I've tried the bellow code which is working but it keeps opening multiple forms every time i call calltest() method. How can i call test() method without opening it's form? Should i move all my methods to another class file? Thanks

```
namespace test1
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
         public void test()
         {
              //code
         }
    ...
    }
}

namespace test1
{
    public partial class SecondForm : Form
    {
         private void calltest()
         {
            MainForm form1 = new MainForm();
            form1.test();
         }
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `test` do?  Can it be made static?

Comment: No it can't be static.

Comment: You have problems with your program structure. You shouldn't really put such a method in a form class.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman i know it's a bit of a mess. What should you recommend me to do? Move all my methods to another class?

Comment: Do you open your SecondForm from the MainForm? With ShowDialog?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes i do it with showdialog

Comment: @PRR21 Then just do whatever you want to do after the form is closed immediately following the call to `ShowDialog`, as that method won't return until the form is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider your design. However, here is a direct answer to your question:

The issue you are having is because each time in the `calltest` method, you are creating a new instance of `MainForm`.

Instead, you should inject the original instance of `MainForm` and store it inside an instance variable inside `SecondForm` like this:

```
public partial class SecondForm : Form
{
     MainForm form1 = null;

     public SecondForm(MainForm main_form)
     {
         form1 = main_form;
     }

     private void calltest()
     {
        form1.test();
     }
...
}
```

Now when you create your instance of `SecondForm`, make sure that you inject the original instance of `MainForm` with something like this:

```
SecondForm second_form = new SecondForm(main_form); //If you are creating this from MainForm, then simply pass `this` as the construction parameter
```

Comment: This is still going to open a second form, just not a third, fourth, etc.

Comment: I've tried that, but my application crashes with null exception on an object of mains form.

Comment: It won't open a form. It only creates it. `Show` and `ShowDialog` opens it.

Comment: @Servy, it seems clear to me from the question, that the OP wants to have 2 forms. This is clear since he is defining a `MainForm` and a `SecondForm`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad And you're creating a *second main form*.  I wouldn't expect him to want two main forms.

Comment: I don't want to open a form, i know how to do that. My second form is only a form with some settings. I just want when the second form is closed to call a method from my mainform (which is already opened).

Comment: @PRR21, do you have an existing instance of `MainForm`? even before `SecondForm` is used?

Comment: @YacoubMassad If follow your logic, OP code does not "open" forms either, but still he claims "it keeps opening multiple forms".

Comment: @IvanStoev, I think he means a new instance will be used instead of the original instance